# Is it possible to create an expandable text field in RSA Archer?

Tags: expandablelistview, archer, rsa-archer-grc

My company is using RSA Archer GRC, there is a text box that can seemingly handle indefinite amount of text. Currently any amount over 5 lines has to be scrolled through in order to read more than that. I would like to be able to configure that field to expand using a side arrow, and collapse using the same object. I asked this question on the Archer community and haven't had any responses for a few weeks.

The only method that I've tried is through the developer selection interface, (not a great programmer).

Answer (score 0):

You could put a custom object on the form that changes the height attribute of the text area. The default style of a text area will be RichTextEditor, which already sets the overflow to auto, so if you collapse the area to a smaller size than the text, scrollbars will automatically appear.

You'll have two challenges with this:

1. Collapsing the text area will not adjust the layout, so there will be a bunch of unused space on the layout.
2. The IDs of the field elements are dynamically generated, so they are not easy to predict.

```js
<button onclick="collapse()">collapse me</button>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
function collapse()
{
     let myTextArea = document.getElementById( "master_DefaultContent_rts_s9518_f27911c_text");
     myTextArea.style.height = "100px";
}
</script>
```